# Invalid classpath to Bundle for ResourceBundle in Netbeans Maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, resourcebundle

I just ported my project to Maven and I'm having issues getting my code to now recognize the existence of a bundle that ResourceBundle is supposed to load, which worked fine before

This is my project structure currently:

```
├───main
│   └───java
│       └───pcd
│           ├───data
│           ├───gui
│           │   ├───base
│           │   ├───bundle
│           │   │   └ Bundle.properties
│           │   ├───dialog
│           │   └ MainFrame.java
│           ├───python
│           └───utils
└───test
    └───java
```

Before, I used to be able to just use this line of code to import the bundle, inside MainFrame.java:

`ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("pcd.gui.bundle.Bundle", Locale.getDefault());`

But this no longer works. I tried putting `src.main.java.` in front of it, with and without `src` as well, but it can't find the Bundle at all.

The MainFrame.java is part of the `pcd.gui` package just to clarify, and the working path is set to two folders above main, so main is located as such: `Project/src/main` where the working path is `Project`.

I'm unsure what other information I can provide as I am new to working with Maven and its structure. This project was an ANT project before migrating it to Maven. I am working on it in NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this doesn't work is because Maven doesn't natively include resource files (like files ending with '.properties') into the build path when running the software.

The way to fix this most efficiently is to simply create a new folder: `src/main/resources' where you will place your` .properties` file.

Then, inside your `.POM` file, include this:

```xml
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This is a plugin that tells Maven to recognize resource files in the new resources folder you just made.

Finally, replace the path to the file in your code to look as such:
`ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle", Locale.getDefault());`

Also, be careful to check if there aren't other bundles being initialized in your code, because NetBeans sometimes includes it into the uneditable code if you ever attempted to do internationalization automatically through the Swing GUI, as was in my case.